# How to show that the product of two binary numbers can be determined in AC1?

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

I was working on a proof to determine that a product cannot be done in AC0, how can a proof that can be done in AC1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication can be done even with stronger restrictions, like $AC^1$ with bounded fan-in.

Proof is little hard to typeset here, but I will outline the sketch and give a link.

1. You shall prove, that addition of two m-bit numbers have $O(m)$ size and constant depth circuit and thus is in $AC^0$. This is pretty simple (start with looking for $O(m)$ depth and then simplify)
2. Then you need to generalize this result to addition of many m-bit numbers and show that it have logarithmic depth and thus in $AC^1$
3. And finally what you are looking for (product in $AC^1$) is simple corollary

Look into those [lecture notes](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/CourseWeb/Math262A_2013F/Scribe12.pdf) for example, where this proof is done in great details.

Comment: AC$^1$ with bounded fan-in is known as NC$^1$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus of course. If you read linked paper, it have this and many more definitions. I just tried not to overcomplicate things here.